# How to remove second square brackets from an array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array something like this:

```
data: [
  [
    {}, {} ... //multiple objects
  ]
]
```

How do I remove those second square brackets? I want it to be changed from `[[{}]]` to `[{}]`.

Comment: `data = data[0]` ... quite simple if you would have looked around a bit though.

Comment: A square bracket within an array would signfy that there is an array within the array.

So, you need to loop through the inner array and push individual objects to a flat array

Comment: `var arr = data[0]` .. whats so big in it?

Comment: The downvotes indicate that we think you did not research this enough before asking the question.

Comment: This seems to be a task for a programming class. The teacher probably saw your code and told you to remove those brackets. Nothing to worry aboit, you can just delete them using the backspace key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten sub-arrays:

```js
const data = [
  [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2}
  ],
  [
    {id: 3},
    {id: 4}
  ]
];

const newData = data.flat();
console.log(newData);
```

If `Array.flat()` is not supported, you can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const data = [
  [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2}
  ],
  [
    {id: 3},
    {id: 4}
  ]
];

const newData = [].concat(...data);
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 5):

Extract first item of your array

```js
var data = [
  [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2}
  ]
]
console.log(data);

var newData = data[0];
console.log(newData);
```